# Combine two lists as key/value pairs in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Example:

```
a = ["a","b"]
b = [("Aa","aA"),("Bb","bB")]

result = {"a":("Aa","aA"),"b":("Bb","bB")}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dict) and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> dict(zip(a, b))
{'a': ('Aa', 'aA'), 'b': ('Bb', 'bB')}
```

Comment: See also: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_zip.asp